# Which aspect should I look at when I can not access sql path although the path correctly exist ?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, flask, sqlalchemy, pytest

The problem is that the error message come out although the pytest print out sql path and the sql file exist in correct directly. Also, the python code works without executing pytest code. 
Even if I moved this test code file to another directly, the same error message comes out.

> Which aspect should I look at ? Is there any specific way to write test code with
>   pytest for accessing db although I dont think that the
>   pytest code itself is wrong.

The test code written with pytest

```
        def test():
            sql_path = "xxx/sql/api/auth/auth.id.sql"
            id_ = 'xxx'
            print('a1' + str(sql_path))
    >       rows = dba.daccess(sql_path, s1=id_)

    test_auth.py:77:
```

The code of access to db written with python（dba.py）

---

```
sql_path = 'xxx/sql/api/auth/auth.id.sql', sql_params = {xxx}

    def daccess(sql_path, **sql_params):
        print('a1'+str(sql_path))

>       f = open(sql_path)
E       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xxx/sql/api/auth/auth.id.sql'
```

Error

```
   ../xxx/common/db/dba.py:28: FileNotFoundError
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    a1<module 'xxx.common.db.dba' from '/Users/xxx/local/xxx/xxx/common/db/dba.py'>
    a1xxx/sql/api/auth/auth.id.sql
    ============================================================================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 4.94 seconds ===============================================================================
```

---

- Technology : python3/pytest/flask/SQLAlchemy

Comment: You should try to pass an absolute path, the current working directory could be different in these two cases

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was also considering this aspect but I wonder the directly of this file. How should I make the test code work on the top working directly as the same as manage.py is working ?